# bring back column info in sde descendant version

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

I have a feature class registered as versioned in sde with editor tracking turned on. In my edit version, I was updating one field for all records but forgot to turn off the editor tracking before editing. So the editor tracking fields are updated under my user name and same edit date in my edit version. I have not posted my edit version to the master version so everything in default version is good and there are still new editing going on in default version. Since we really want to preserve the editor tracking info and not to mess up with the edits, what is the best way to fix this problem?